# User with multiple lost accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users

Something weird appened in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/324929/how-do-i-get-a-level-3-locator-map), a couple of "answers" talk about lost credentials, and it seems that these users are actually the same person, asking for help, who clearly can't log-in:

- [Minecraft_Maniac22](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/229445/minecraft-maniac22)
- [OgMinecraftManiac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/264528/ogminecraftmaniac)
- [ToppsGuy1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/278463/toppsguy1)

Is there anything we can do to help this guy and stop his "madness" of posting answers from different unregistered accounts every once in a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two proper courses of action they can take.  One would be to reset their credentials, using the [password reset option](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) available when trying to log in (though I believe this will only work with registered accounts), or  use the [Contact Us page](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and request that their profiles be merged, as this [Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240425/342074) discusses.  It looks like previously community moderators could do this, but not anymore.

I think it would go:

1. Fill out the Contact Us form.
2. Wait for profiles to be merged.
3. Once the profiles are merged, they should be able to rename it if they want, and be on their way.

Comment: So it's up to the user? Or can we ask a community mod?

Comment: @pinckerman I think the only thing we can really do is reach out to the user and provide them with these options for them to try.